# Visual Studio Mac 2017 - Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 to 2.1.1

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio-mac

I keep getting this error when trying to run my code in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac. The code builds and runs fine in Visual Studio 2017 for Windows, and I can also run it fine in VS Code with the C# extension. If I perform a dotnet build on the projects at the command line it works fine. Looking for some help. [image]

Comment: I suspect you are running into this bug - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/365280/nuget-restores-the-wrong-version-of-microsoftaspne.html I am guessing you have 2.1.3 specified in your .csproj file?

Comment: Yes I have it specified in the .csproj file. Is that wrong?

Comment: It'd be great to get some feedback on this one. I've tried to switch to doing all development on my mac without switching between mac and windows. This is the only thing giving me grief at the moment. My current workaround is to disable the package restore on loading the solution, and run dotnet restore at the command line. This seems to work thus far.

Comment: Having the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App PackageReference with a version in the .csproj is fine. Unfortunately there is a bug in Visual Studio for Mac which causes the wrong version to be restored. There is a fix for this but it has not yet made it into a release.

Answer (score 0):

Original thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/365280/nuget-restores-the-wrong-version-of-microsoftaspne.html

You can upgrade your Visual Studio to version 7.8 Preview (Beta) - This contains the fix for wrong Nuget version restoration.